# MLKit Pose Detection: How to measure angle when the skeleton turns sideways?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to measure angle between points shoulder, hip and ankle (to identify how much lift person's leg). When the person stands on front of the camera it works well but when the person turns sideways it fails. How can I handle it?